# It is possible to post dragged and dropped files with a normal form?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I have a webpage which right now allows normal `<input type="file".../>` type of uploads, it does a multi part post. It is possible for me to reuse the same form post but send files which were dragged and dropped? The reason for this is so we don't have to change the backend. I've already done it with XHR and FormData but that would require some changes to our back end to work properly.

Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention I mean HTML5 file drag and drop.

Comment: What kind of “drag&drop” are we talking about? If it’s just the normal browser behavior of letting a user drag&drop a file from outside into an input type=file … then that should all be handled by the browser itself, and require no additional work to behave like any other file upload where the user chose the file via the “browse” button of the upload field … those are just two different implementations of file choosing in the browser’s UI.

Comment: I had no idea you could drag and drop into a "browse" button, but no that is not what I meant, I meant the html5 drag and drop using the html5 file api stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, take a look at [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

This provide what you need, and it uses HTML5 API when it is available, and some fallback techniques when it's not.

Comment: This is not a normal form. It uses AJAX for uploading. The OP asks if it can be done without the use of XHR (AJAX).

Comment: It still uses the HTML 5 File API when it's available, I don't understand why the backend needs request from a "real form", the file is uploaded with the multipart encoding, and it is giving a field name which you can configure what would be - the default is `files[]`, and you can instanciate it around a "real form" to send additional field data. At the end of the day you cannot tell the difference in the request format either. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data